# Tornado: url in external css file

Tags: html, css, tornado, static-files

In tornado's html template, one recommendation about specifying static file path is that we should use **static_url** rather than hard-coding the path. For example,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{static_url("css/frontpage.css")}}">
```

But it doesn't work if I try to do something similar in the external "frontpage.css" file, such as

```
body { 
background-image: static_url("img/bgimg.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Of course, I can hard-code the path as "/static/img/bgimg.jpg" to avoid this. However, I think there should be a more proper way to handle this. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your url in the css is defined as a relative url you should be fine, because it will be relative to the css file. The reason that you want to use static_url in the html template is so that you can easily relocate the static assets to a CDN or another web server so that it is not being served from the tornado instance.

Comment: The other benefit of using static_url is that "the static_url function creates a hash based on the content of the file and appends it to the end of the URL, which ensures that browsers will always load the latest version of a file instead of relying on a previously cached version". Given its impact,  just not so sure about the way to hard-coding url in css file. So this should be also modified accordingly if relocating to another web server later?